# How to replace NA's in rows with a fixed value by group?

Tags: r, group-by, na

I'm trying to find a way to replace NA values in my code with a fixed value.

```
Example


Animals    Value    
Dog         13
Dog         20
Dog         27
Dog         35
Dog         NA
Dog         NA
Dog         NA
Cat         17
Cat         24
Cat         31
Cat         NA
Cat         NA
Mouse       100
Mouse       107
Mouse       NA
Mouse       NA
Mouse       NA
Mouse       NA
```

What I would like to do is replace NA values with multiples of 7 so it would look like:

```
Animals    Value    
Dog         13
Dog         20
Dog         27
Dog         34
Dog         41
Dog         48
Dog         55
Cat         17
Cat         24
Cat         31
Cat         38
Cat         45
Mouse       100
Mouse       107
Mouse       114
Mouse       121
Mouse       128
Mouse       135
```

I tried looking into the "fill"  and "complete" functions, but from what I gathered, it usually fills NA's with a previous row value or fixed value. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: in your input example, the fourth value is 35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `seq` after grouping by 'Animals'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(Animals) %>% 
   mutate(Value = seq(first(Value), length.out = n(), by = 7))
# A tibble: 18 x 2
# Groups:   Animals [3]
#   Animals Value
#   <chr>   <dbl>
# 1 Dog        13
# 2 Dog        20
# 3 Dog        27
# 4 Dog        34
# 5 Dog        41
# 6 Dog        48
# 7 Dog        55
# 8 Cat        17
# 9 Cat        24
#10 Cat        31
#11 Cat        38
#12 Cat        45
#13 Mouse     100
#14 Mouse     107
#15 Mouse     114
#16 Mouse     121
#17 Mouse     128
#18 Mouse     135
```

---

Or another option is `coalesce`

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(Animals) %>%
   mutate(Value = coalesce(Value, seq(first(Value), length.out = n(), by = 7L)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Animals = c("Dog", "Dog", "Dog", "Dog", "Dog", 
"Dog", "Dog", "Cat", "Cat", "Cat", "Cat", "Cat", "Mouse", "Mouse", 
"Mouse", "Mouse", "Mouse", "Mouse"), Value = c(13L, 20L, 27L, 
35L, NA, NA, NA, 17L, 24L, 31L, NA, NA, 100L, 107L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

Comment: For some reason, when I run your code, the Values add a sequence of multiples of 7 from 13  - 126. So values would equal 13, 20, 27, 34 .... 126 regardless of the group

Comment: @Jiihong I checked your expected, it is matching with my output.  Only difference in yoour input is the value 35 changed to 34, and that is also the case in my solution ass well

Comment: Yes, It checks out. Thank you for the answer. Much appreciated!